# Illegal Number - Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell

My code was working fine then the next day I get

```
./Desktop/audiolog.sh: 32: [: /proc/: unexpected operator

./Desktop/audiolog.sh: 13: ./Desktop/audiolog.sh: Illegal number: 08
```

Is it perhaps the number 08 within the seconds? Any pointers will be great thanks

```
#!/bin/sh  

DAY=$(date +%d)                          
MO=$(date +%m)                             
YR=$(date +%y)                 
SE=$(date +%S)                             
H=$(date +%H)                                                           
M=$(date +%M)  

NOW=$(date)

DURATION=$(((60 - M) * 60-SE))

PART=$(find /mnt/hgfs/Audio\ Log/ -type f -name "RBLoggerAudio ${DAY}-${MO}-${YR}\ ${H}*" | wc -l)

reset

echo "Recording for $DAY $MO $YR - $H 00"
echo "Started at $NOW"
echo "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -"

if [ "$PART" -eq 0 ]
then
    arecord -f cd -c 1 -d$DURATION -t raw -v -v | lame -b 64 -q8 -mm -r - /mnt/hgfs/Audio\ Log/"RBLoggerAudio "$DAY-$MO-$YR\ $H"00".mp3    
else
    arecord -f cd -c 1 -d$DURATION -t raw -v -v | lame -b 64 -q8 -mm -r - /mnt/hgfs/Audio\ Log/"RBLoggerAudio "$DAY-$MO-$YR\ $H"00 - Part - "$PART.mp3
fi


pid=$(ps -opid= -C audiolog.sh)
while [ -d /proc/$pid ] ; do
    sleep 1
done && ./Desktop/audiolog.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
while [ -d /proc/$pid ] ; do
```

with

```
while [ -d "/proc/$pid" ] ; do
```

Comment: Really? single quotes?

Comment: Thanks to both @Jdamian and fedorqui to mention it. I edited accordingly.

Comment: There's a space at the front of `$pid` (that's the reason it fails in the first place). This test checks if a directory `/proc/ 1234` (with space) exists and will always return false.

Comment: @Wintermute my solution had solved his problem it seems so my solution is right in this case.

Comment: No, the script just doesn't complain anymore and OP hasn't realized that the test doesn't test for what he wanted. There's a race condition now.

Comment: Well bro I just helped according to the Error OP getting not the problem in logic or anything else.

Comment: I'm sure that's really helpful. OP, if you're still reading this, an actual solution that doesn't wreck the program logic is to use `pid=$(pidof audiolog.sh)`. Encasing the `/proc/$pid` in double quotes is good style but not the cause of your particular error.

Comment: @Wintermute if you want you can edit my answer and add your point of view with it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Wintermute I will implement this now. Although the accepted answer works as expected I think you have a valid point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem: leading zeroes**

You're using a Bourne-style shell that interprets leading zeroes on numbers as octal notation in arithmetic expressions.  The shell objects ("Illegal number") if a number with a leading zero isn't actually an octal number, e.g.

```
$ n=077
$ echo $(( n ))
63
$ n=088
$ echo $(( n ))
sh: Illegal number: 088
```

If your `/bin/sh` is `bash`, the error message is slightly different:

```
bash: 088: value too great for base (error token is "088")
```

Whenever your date minutes variable (`$M`) or seconds variable (`$SE`) happens to start with a leading zero followed by the digit 8 or 9, you get this error when you do this line of arithmetic in your shell script:

```
DURATION=$(((60 - M) * 60-SE))
```

**Fixing the leading zero problem**

Since your numbers are time and thus will never be negative and will only have one leading zero, you can make the shell strip the single leading zero as the variable is substituted:

```
$ M=08
$ SE=09
$ DURATION=$(((60 - M) * 60-SE))
sh: Illegal number: 08
$ DURATION=$(((60 - ${M#0}) * 60-${SE#0}))
$ echo $DURATION
3111
```

If your `/bin/sh` is actually `bash`, you can instead use the `10#` syntax (but note this won't work for other `/bin/sh` shells such as `dash` used on Ubuntu, nor does it work for negative numbers, but it does work for more than one leading zero):

```
$ DURATION=$(((60 - 10#$M) * 60-10#$SE))
```

For a general solution that works in all Bourne-style shells, with any number of leading zeroes, with positive or negative numbers, you have to avoid shell arithmetic and resort to an external program, e.g. the legacy `expr`:

```
$ DURATION=$( expr \( 60 - $M \) \* 60 - $SE )
```

I think `expr` used to be built-in to shells before shells had their own arithmetic processing, but neither `bash` nor `dash` have it built-in today, so it really requires a call to an external program `expr(1)` and is thus orders of magnitude slower than shell built-in arithmetic.  Be careful about using it in a loop.

There are other questions similar to this on Stack Overflow, but each of them has only half of the truth in the answers and the answers don't work for all numbers in all Bourne shell variants.  I think my answer above summarizes all the possible cases.